# Are all Angular 4 browsers also supported by ng-Bootstrap?

Tags: ng-bootstrap

Angular 4 supports IE 9 and above. Does ng-Bootstrap also support the same browsers as Angular 4. Is ng-Bootstrap using flex?

Answer (score 0):

According to their documentation, no. Only IE10+
https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Our [getting started page](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) is very clear about supported browsers:

> We strive to support the same browsers and versions as supported by
>   both Bootstrap 4 and Angular, whichever is more restrictive.

In the current situation Angular 4+ supports IE9+ but Bootstrap 4 dropped IE9 support and works only with IE10+. As we are building on both Angular *and* Bootstrap we've got no choice but to support the most restrictive set of browsers. In practice it means IE10+.

Comment: Does it means I could override bootstrap4 with bootstrap3 class? so I could use ng-bootstrap in IE9? Our project now upgrade to angular2 but should also support IE9 browser...